# How to set the mouse position under X11 (linux desktop)?

Tags: mouse, x11

I'm wondering how to set the mouse cursor position under X11? Is it possible at all and if, where do I have to look for appropriate functions? X window system, KDE/Gnome/...?

Comment: Well, which are you using?  X, KDE, Gnome, or something else? Each has their own solution.

Comment: Well... actually meant the *mouse* cursor :-/ And I am looking for a solution that is as universal as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're using X, so what you probably want is [`XWarpPointer`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XWarpPointer.html).  To give an absolute position on the whole screen, use the Root Window as dest window.

(You can get a quick and dirty list of X functions using `ls /usr/share/man/man3/ | grep '^X'`)

Comment: See http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XWarpPointer.html

To give an absolute position on the whole screen, use the Root Window as dest window.

Comment: How to set root window as destination window?

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is old, but I just discovered xdotool and it seems great:

http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Comment: `xdotool` is amazing!

Comment: @AkiRoss The download link on that webpage is DEAD.

Answer (score 1):

Try using xte command (part of xautomation package). Details [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6415)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in an xterm, the Xterm understands ANSI control codes. There is a list of these codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 0):

To do from a shell script, use the [xwit](http://www.slack.com/sw/xwit-man.html) commandline tool.

Comment: This link is dead.