# How do I control the cursor on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, cursor, dllimport

In Windows 10 this is easy. You import the DLL "User32.dll" and call the SetCursorPos(int x, int y) function, for example.

I was looking for the Linux/Unix/OSX equivalents?

Comment: On the JVM you can move the cursor with [java.awt.Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove-int-int-) - might be worth looking into how that is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one equivalent to [SetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), depending on whether you are running in a *terminal* or in the *X Window* system.

- in a terminal, using escape sequences (e.g., [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html)), or
- in X, using a feature called "Warp Pointer"

The choice really depends on what you are trying to do.  For a simple program, you *could* run it in a terminal (or terminal window).  Warping the pointer is not done often in X, but is well-known enough to make it easy to find discussion on the topic.  Programming in X (no matter what toolkit you use), however, is more complicated than programming for a terminal.

Further reading:

- [How to set the mouse position under X11 (linux desktop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578804/how-to-set-the-mouse-position-under-x11-linux-desktop)
- [How to set mouse cursor position in C on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433447/how-to-set-mouse-cursor-position-in-c-on-linux)
- [Screen Updating and Cursor Movement Optimization: A Library Package](https://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/19.curses/paper.pdf)
- [Bash Prompt HOWTO: 6.2. Cursor Movement](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)

Comment: Yeah, I still have to import a share object file, though. Not sure which to use?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.  For a simple program, running in a terminal is simpler than building an X application.